# When do I use the gerundive vs. participle forms of a verb in Latin?

Tags: grammar-choice, participle, gerund

When do I use the gerundive vs. participle forms of a verb in Latin?

Comment: A typical Latin verb has one gerundive and several participles. Do you only want to compare *amandus* and *amans*, or should *amatus* and *amaturus* be included, too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that your question will become a lot clearer when you realize that the **gerundive is a participle**: specifically, it is the **future passive participle**.

This is thus not a question of choosing *between* a gerundive and a participle, but rather choosing *which* participle (tense and voice) to use. Here is a brief overview of the kinds of participles of *amare* (to love):

1. **Present active**: *amans, -ntis*

   - *mater amans*: "a loving mother" or "a mother who loves"
2. **Future active**: *amaturus, -i*

   - *mater amatura*: "a mother who is about to love"
3. **Perfect passive**: *amatus, -i* (N.B. this has an active meaning with deponent verbs)

   - *mater amata*: "a beloved mother" or "a mother who was loved"
4. **Future passive**: *amandus, -i*

   - *mater amanda*: "a mother who shall be loved"

Note that this future passive meaning most often conveys a sense of obligation, i.e. "a mother to be loved" = "a mother who should be loved."

If you provide further details about your use case, I can specify further, but as you see there is a pretty clear distinction between each participial form.

Comment: As an interesting aside, the absence of a perfect active participle (as there is in Greek) often forces such thoughts to be translated using ablative absolute + perfect passive participle, e.g. "having visited the store" becomes "the store having been visited..."

Comment: I didn't know "**the gerundive is a participle**: specifically, it is the **future passive participle**." Thank you. Also, are the 4 tenses/voices you enumerate all there are for Latin participles?